# RoR passing meeting information into a modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have a calendar that has meetings fed onto it.

**Controller:**

```
def index
  @meetings = current_user.meetings.all
end
```

**View**

```
<%= render "calendar", meetings: @meetings  %>
```

**Rendering:**

```
<%= month_calendar events: meetings do |date, meetings| %>
  <%= date %>
  <% meetings.each do |meeting| %>
    <div>
      <% unless meeting.complete == true%>
        <% if meeting.end_time.to_date < Date.today %>
        <%= link_to "❗️ #{meeting.name}", meeting, class: "link" %>
        <% elsif meeting.end_time.to_date == Date.today %>
        <%= link_to " #{meeting.name}", meeting, class: "link" %>
        <% else meeting.end_time.to_date > Date.today %>
        <%= link_to meeting.name, meeting, class: "link" %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have managed to get the link to fire a modal, but cannot figure out how to pass in the singular meeting information.
The below code shows links as individual meetings, but the modal only comes up with the first meeting information on all links:

```
<% if meeting.end_time.to_date < Date.today %>
  <%= link_to "❗️ #{meeting.name}", meeting, {:remote => true, 'data-bs-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-bs-target' => '#task_modal'} %>
  <div class="modal fade" id="task_modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Task name: <%= meeting.name %><br>Urgency Level: <%= meeting.priority %></h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <%= meeting.body %>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: At a glance: Is it because you are setting the same target for every modal? (`#task_modal`)? Do you need to change this to something unique, e.g. `"#task_modal_#{meeting.id}"`? You also have duplicate `staticBackdropLabel` elements inside, which could be causing problems. (Maybe that should be a class, not an id?)

Comment: Thank you. passing the meeting.id into the #task_modal fixed the issue. The staticBackdropLabel was leftover form the bootstrap example - it went unnoticed so thank you for pointing that out too.